# gulp-sass removed my css code - losing code on compiled file

Tags: node-sass, gulp-sass

I am using gulp for compile compress my css code from the scss part code

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

var sassOptions = {
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
}

gulp.task('scss', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./static/scss/' + name.src + '/*.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: plugins.notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>") }))
    .pipe(plugins.sass(sassOptions))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css/' + name.dist));

  gulp.src('./static/scss/' + name.src + '/*.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: plugins.notify.onError("Error: <%= error.message %>") }))
    .pipe(plugins.sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(plugins.rename({ extname:'.full.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css/' + name.dist));

  gulp.src('./static/css/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.plumber({ errorHandler: function(err) {
      plugins.notify.onError({
        title: "Gulp error in " + err.plugin,
        message: err.toString()
      })(err);
    }}))
    .pipe(plugins.sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'))
  done();
});
```

Problem here is losing my some code
[git diff code after compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQfgG.jpg)

seem gulp merged my two lines code to one

```css
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
          filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
          
          
==>> filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
```

May be related with gulp config or gulp-sass plugin options but i do not found how to prevent it. Any one can help

Answer (score 0):

Autoprefixer is likely stripping out vendor prefixes that are no longer required/supported in modern browsers